# Ignoring exceptions such as number_format_exception when searching in Elasticsearch 6.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this field in my mapping:

```
          "status" : {
            "type" : "byte"
          },
```

When I run the following query:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status": {
        "value": "blah"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"term\" : {\n    \"status\" : {\n      \"value\" : \"blah\",\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "0JkHFuT3TjS6luoEZTtBDw",
        "index": "my_index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_index",
        "node": "psHswpZCQlm-7fwW4IYlcw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"term\" : {\n    \"status\" : {\n      \"value\" : \"blah\",\n      \"boost\" : 1.0\n    }\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "0JkHFuT3TjS6luoEZTtBDw",
          "index": "my_index",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"blah\""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I get the value to search on from a filter form and since this is happening in many places, I don't want to refactor a ton of code to validate my input.

So my question is, how can I ignore such errors, so the query just doesn't return anything or ignores this filter in particular - either is acceptable.

Or alternatively, is there any way to change the behaviour of the query to just try and cast the supplied value to an integer to match the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

In `query_string` you can use `lenient` parameter to ignore format errors:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "status"
      ],
      "query": "blah",
      "lenient": true
    }
  }
}
```

For more details see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)